# How should I display download links to only certain users in ActiveAdmin rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to hide download links according to user role of logged in user in Active Admin

I want to be doing it like this but I'm not able access current_user

```
index :download_links => current_user.admin? do
# columns
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be incomplete.
Guess- You have a `User` model, `id, role,` etc as attributes
First, Find the user first based on id, `@current_user = User.find(params[:id)`
Then,

```
if @current_user.admin?
# do not show the links
end
```

Hope you need this to use in views, so use along `<% rails tag %>`

Comment: I am not able to access current_user and I am not using it from views.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `current_admin_user`, b/c the activeadmin user is called `AdminUser

[Devise helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55-L57)

Or u can define your own method in `active_admin.rb` like:

```
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

Comment: I have used my own model as admin user and I have already changed the active_admin.rb